# Plotly on_click functionality on streamlit python

Tags: python, plotly, streamlit

I am developing a graph with plotly, it works well but I want to display some information using st.write on the screen when any point on the plot is clicked. In plotly, this can be easily done using the on_click method. But it doesn't work on streamlit. I have tried another library called plotly events, but it generates a black and white graph in the newer versions of streamlit.

The graph is a simple scatterplot.

```
import streamlit as st
import plotly.express as px

def click(trace, points, selector):
    st.write("hello")

x = [1,2,3]
y = [4,5,6]
z = [10,11,2]
fig = px.scatter(x=x, y=y, size = z)
fig.data[0].on_click(click) 
st.plotly_chart(fig, use_container_width=True)
```

btw, it doesn't matter if the line with the fig.data[0] line is put after st.plotly_chart line because its still not working. plz help

Answer (score -1):

Here is the code that integrates Plotly's on-click functionality with Streamlit and displays information when a point on the scatter plot is clicked:

```py
import streamlit as st
import plotly.express as px

def click(trace, points, selector):
    selected_point = points.point_inds[0]
    x_val = fig.data[0].x[selected_point]
    y_val = fig.data[0].y[selected_point]
    st.write(f"Clicked point: x={x_val}, y={y_val}")

x = [1, 2, 3]
y = [4, 5, 6]
z = [10, 11, 2]
fig = px.scatter(x=x, y=y, size=z)
fig.data[0].on_click(click)

st.plotly_chart(fig, use_container_width=True)
```

In this code, the `click` function is called when a point on the scatter plot is clicked. It retrieves the selected point's index, and then accesses the corresponding `x` and `y` values from the scatter plot data. The information is then displayed using `st.write`. This way, when you click on a point in the scatter plot, the information about that point will be shown on the Streamlit interface.

Comment: This doesn't work. There is a discussion on streamlit about this and it has no updated solutuons. I mean this is baaically thr code I shared, how can it work?

Comment: This looks like a solution from Chatgpt....